# R programming: parpvclust script getting killed

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I'm currently trying to run parallel hierarchical clustering via the pvclust library, using the command `parPvclust`. The dataset I'm using is 57 rows by 30000 columns. I run the program. And from my nohup.out I get to the following:

```
`[1] "2015-09-23 11:31:31 EDT"
 [1] "Data transposed"
 [1] "2015-09-23 11:31:39 EDT"
 [1] "start clustering"
 Multiscale bootstrap...`
```

Then separately from my nohup.out. The command line spits out `Killed`, but they're are still R processes running if I run `top`. Here's a pic:
[image]

Here's my script.

```
#parallel clustering via pvclust library
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(parallel)
library(pvclust)

nabec <- fread("/labshare/Nick/projects/nabec/pilot/normalized.transcripts.usable.autosomal.1.txt")

#transpose file
nabecCohort.T <- dcast.data.table(melt(nabec, id.vars = "ID"), variable ~ ID)
testNabec <- nabecCohort.T[2:58, 2:dim(nabecCohort.T)[2], with = F]
testNabec <- sapply(testNabec, as.numeric)

Sys.time()
print("Data transposed")

cl <- makeCluster(23)

Sys.time()
print("start clustering")
nabec.pv <- parPvclust(cl,testNabec[1:57,],nboot=1000)
```

I found this post, but it doesn't help all that much.

What other trouble shooting can I do? Any ideas what's going on? I don't get an error like "Cannot allocate vector of size.." or anything.

edit: also the script runs fine with smaller subsamples of the data set (57 row * 1000 columns)

Comment: Programming errors of any kind in the C and Fortran code can cause this. The message `Killed` occurs when the process was killed e.g. by the system or admin. You may want to check the output of `dmesg`, for example - because it does look like you are running out of memory.

Comment: Cool Thanks! based of `dmesg`. I think your right @Anony-Mousse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system may have run out of memory.

Please see the output of `dmesg`.

When your operating system runs out of memory, as a very last measure, it invokes the `OOM killer`. It picks a process based on a number of criteria, and kills this process to free up some system memory. If this happen, it will be visible in `dmesg` and in your system log.

It looks like your primary `R` process was killed, when your system ran out of memory hard. It may help to actually *reduce* the swap size, if you want to fail earlier. Swap just needs big enough to store unneeded system parts (e.g. services not in use).

Unfortunately, R can be very memory hungry. It may help to e.g. write `testNabec[1:57,]` to a file, and in a *fresh* session, load it again. Try to find out, which lines cause the most memory consumption.

Oh, and of course kill zombie processes. You seem to have a number of `R` processes running, each using 10 GB of RAM...

Comment: The dmesg log showed the processes was killed because it was eating too much memory. The`parPVclust` line is the one killing it. I might have to move to another function or filter my data some more it seems. Thanks for the info. @Anony-Mousse

Comment: @Anony_Mousse. I was hoping you could expand on "It may help to actually reduce the swap size, if you want to fail earlier. Swap just needs big enough to store unneeded system parts (e.g. services not in use)."  As I don't even know what "swap size" is?

Comment: Swapping takes time. If your system is running out of memory, and resorts to swapping, that is a waste of time. Better have it fail right away, instead of trying to survive a little bit longer by swapping (and then run out of memory nevertheless). The only things that should go into swap is what you do *not* need for your task. E.g. you might be running a printing service. It uses some megabytes of memory. That should go to swap, unless you plan to print.

Comment: Swap size is the size of your swap partition. You have 8 GB of swap configured and used.

Comment: So I figured out that R holds the object I'm trying to cluster in memory for each node (not sure if thats the right word) that I've used to make my computing cluster (e.g. `cl <- makeCluster(23)`) Since the server I'm working on only has ~180gb it would crash as 23 * 10.9GB > ~180GB. However, if I simply reduced `cl <- makeCluster(8)` it works.  Just thought you should know how I solved it.